# Heronian triangles

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, triangles

How to prove that all Heronian triangles can be found using formulas described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle#Exact_formula_for_Heronian_triangles)?

I understand that the described substitution will give Heronian triangle, but how to prove that using the described substitution will give all Heronian triangles (with scaling solutions, for example $(12,10,10)$ is obtained when multiplying $(6,5,5)$ by $2$)?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114112/heronian-triangle-generator

Comment: [This](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/20073/20073-pdf.pdf) appears to be the Carmichael publication referred to in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

Well, understanding that Heronian triangles are cyclic is a start. So the scaled up($\times n$, say) version of a Heronian would fit precisely into a circle of twice the diameter.

Comment: What do you mean, "Heronian triangles are cyclic"? Every triangle, Heronian or not, can be inscribed in a circle.