# Integer Triangle Radicals conjecture

Tags: geometry, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, triangles

An integer sided triangle has an area $A$. [Heronian triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronianTriangle.html) areas have no radical, or radical 1. Otherwise, $4 A$ will always be of the form $a\sqrt{r}$, where $r$ is the [squarefree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html) radical of the triangle. For the first 24 squarefree numbers, here are the smallest triangles with a given radical.

[image: smallest triangles of a given radical]

Now consider sequence $G$.
$$G = (24,8,1,0,8,8,3,0,8,24,1,0)$$

Integer Triangle Radicals conjecture:
For a triangle with radical $r$, let $j = r \mod{12}$.
Then value $4 A/\sqrt{r}$ is divisible by $G_j$ (with $j \in \{1,...,12\})$.

Stated another way, $G_j$ is the GCD of all $4 A/\sqrt{r}$ values corresponding to a particular radical $r$.

Another picture: 
[image: Triangle Radicals]

I've got data from a few million integer triangles suggesting this conjecture is true (supporting code at [Triangle Radicals](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/847872) ). All Heronian triangles have area divisible by 6, based on the [Brahmagupta parametric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle). If this conjecture is true, that hints there might be a more powerful parametric form that classifies all integer triangles.

Does a proof exist?

Mini-challenge:
For radical 953, my scalenes are {{528, 681, 697}, {533, 680, 693}, {561, 656, 689}}.
For radical 977, my scalenes are {{567, 690, 697}, {612, 657, 685}}.
Can someone find triangles with radicals 953 or 977 where $4A$ is divisible by 8, but not 16?

This came out of studying [Wheel Graphs with Integer Edges](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WheelGraphsWithIntegerEdges/).  I noticed all integer-edged wheel graphs with largest edge $<10$ were composed of triangles with exactly 1 or 2 types of radical. Any counterexamples to that?

[image: An integer wheel]

Comment: Is $j = 0 - 11$ meant to be read as $j \in \{0, \ldots, 11\}$?

Comment: What direction should I look to understand how this conjecture implies there are 8 more parametric forms? Also, I located a proof for 6 dividing the area of Heron triangles [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0112239.pdf) (prop 1.3) via [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#cite_ref-Friche_16-1) citation.

Comment: I noticed in the Brahmagupta parametric formula if you let k be the square root of a nonsquare integer, the side lengths remain integers, but the area is not an integer.

Comment: Chris -- I fixed the $j$, and rewrote the suggestion on parametric forms. Josh -- Yes, I think Brahmagupta is on to something there.

Comment: Maybe this parameterization help?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944814/areas-of-primitive-heron-triangles-that-are-perfect-squares/945350#945350

Comment: um... isn't this equivalent to looking at $(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)(a+b+c)$ modulo $192$ and checking that there are a whole bunch of values that can't be obtained ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full solution, but I think it should help. First, define

$$x = b + c - a, \quad y = a + c - b, \quad z = a + b - c.$$

Then, the area is $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{xyz(x + y + z)}$. Suppose we are looking at what areas we can get with squarefree part $r$. Now, consider values for $x$, $y$, and $z$ of the form

$$x = r, \quad y = s^2, \quad z = \left(\frac{r + s^2 - 1}{2}\right)^2,$$

so that $x + y + z = \left( \frac{r + s^2 + 1}{2} \right)^2$. Here, $s$ can be any integer whose parity is the opposite of $r$. Then, we are basically looking for possible integer values of

$$s \left( \frac{r + s^2 - 1}{2} \right)\left( \frac{r + s^2 + 1}{2} \right).$$

For large enough primes $p$, it shouldn't be too hard to find values of $s$ such that the above expression is not divisible by $p$. So already we know the desired gcd doesn't contain large prime factors. Then, it remains to check some small cases like $p = 2, 3, 5$.