# Infinite Right Rational Triangles With a Given Area.

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It can be proven using elliptic curves that if there is one right rational triangle with a given area, then there are an infinite amount.

AFAIK, there is no published elementary proof. Am I correct? If I have one, would it be worth trying to publish?

Comment: What is the correct rational triangle?  Write an equation in which this representation.  You can use Heron's formula.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944814/areas-of-primitive-heron-triangles-that-are-perfect-squares/945350#945350

Comment: How is that relevant? There is no "correct rational triangle". The only requirement is that they have a right angle and then there is an infinite number of them.

Comment: The angle here at all to do with it. The only parameter which does not change is the area. The shape of a triangle, the sides and the angles can be different. And you can only use Heron's formula.  If you think look at it differently - write the equation in the formal form to avoid confusion.

Comment: @individ Are you mis-translating "right rational triangle" by any chance? That would be a triangle with rational sides and a "right" angle of $90^\circ$. "Right" means ["right angle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_angle) in that context, not "correct".

Comment: Then, these triangles cannot be an infinite number.

Comment: They are infinite in number. It's a well established fact.

Comment: Then give an example.  Write a parameterization of the solutions of this equation.  $ps(p^2-s^2)=1$

Comment: @individ for example, 5 is the area of a right rational triangle and there are infinite such right rational triangles with that area. Google the __congruent number problem__