# Integral side lengths and area

Tags: geometry, number-theory

Is there an acute triangle of integral side lengths, integral area and nonintegral altitudes?

Edit: if you were wondering, Heron's formula states that $$S_{ABC}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2+2a^2b^2-a^4-b^4-c^4}$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the side lengths of the triangle.  The condition for acuteness is $b^2+c^2>a^2$ if $a$ is the longest side.

Context: Without the condition of acuteness, I have made this question: for which primes $p$ is there a triangle with sides $p$, $x$, $y$ satisfying the same conditions above?  With the transformation into the variables $p$, $x$, $x+k$, one obtains a Pell-like equation which one may show admits a solution only when $4|p-1$, and further show that one can jump from there to a solution with nonintegral altitudes (I will have to check my proof of this again, but it does lead to 5-29-30 and 13-150-157).  However, this means that the other two sides are quite big, and so the triangle ceases to be acute, leading directly to my question.

Comment: Write a system of equations. So not clear what to look for. Ambiguous wording.

Comment: Sorry, last time I checked, $30^2-29^2=59>5^2$ though, and $157^2-150^2=2149>13^2$

Comment: There's only one equation really, which is Heron's formula, but I will write it in anyway if you feel that would aid your understanding.

Comment: Heron's formula comes down to this decision...  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944814/areas-of-primitive-heron-triangles-that-are-perfect-squares/945350#945350

Comment: Thank you. I seem to have failed in forgetting the key phrase primitive heronian triangles.

Comment: If it is a heronian triangle, its area is an integer, and all its side lengths, then the area which is a half of the product of the (length of) altitude by the corresponding base, thus at worst a half integer. Is that right ?

Comment: @JeanMarie If you do the computation this is clearly not true for example the area of thee 5-29-30 triangle is 72 and the altitude on the 29 side is of length $144/29$ which is clearly neither integral nor half-integral.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the mis understanding